# Android audio playing

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am playing audio from http link using media player and I release the mediaPlayer onStop() of the activity in which the mediaPlayer plays the song. I want the song to continue playing unless user exits from the app ie exits from the home page. how can i stop and release the media player from the home page?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) that plays the music and then your App will just send message to the service.